# Keep jquery .addClass active after click, my div just reverts if i dont hold down mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an animation that expands a tiled div tag when you click the div, however I can't seem to get the active class to hold after the click, I have to hold down the mouse button or it will revert to its previous size, im not sure why.

I didn't create a jfiddle because its to hard to get everything to work right with out my custom stuff

http://snomada.com/angular_test/

is a live example.

My friend helped me out with a jsfiddle and it works but when i replicated with my code it doesnt work

http://jsfiddle.net/inpursuit/g6pf2ye1/3/

solved

```
body{
    background: url(../images/banner.jpg);
    background-size: 2000px 2000px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#content{
    top:55px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px;
    left:7%;
}


.tile-container{
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
   -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transform: scale(1.0);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   transform: scale(1.0);
}

/*.tile-container:active,
.tile-container .test {
   -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   -moz-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   -o-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   transform: translate(0px,-100%);

   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
   -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transform: scale(1.0);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   transform: scale(1.0);
   width:450px;
   height:350px;
}

/*.tile-container:active > .tile,
.tile-container .test > .tile {
   -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   -moz-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   -o-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   background-size: 450px 350px;

}
*/
.tile-container{
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  overflow:hidden;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
   -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transform: scale(1.0);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   transform: scale(1.0);
   background-size: 450px 350px;
}

.tile-container.beenclicked {
   -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   -moz-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   -o-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   transform: translate(0px,-100%);

   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
   -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transform: scale(1.0);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   transform: scale(1.0);
   background-size: 450px 350px;
   width:450px;
   height:350px;
}

.tile-container.beenclicked > .tile{
   -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   -moz-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   -o-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   background-size: 450px 350px;

}


.tile{
  background:inherit;
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
  float:left;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
}

.circular {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;

    }

.circular img {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    border:10px;
    border-color:#fff;
    }

/*
.active-tile > .tile{
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
  -o-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
  transform: translate(0px,-100%);
}
*/


<html>
    <head>
        <title>Relic</title>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MetroJs.css">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/MetroJs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/social.js"></script>     

<script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');


$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".tile-container").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("beenclicked");
    });
});

</script>

</head>

<body class="metro" ng-app="userProfile" ng-controller="ProfileController as post">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Relic</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

<div id="content">

                <div class="tile-container" ng-repeat="userpost in post.userPost" >
                    <div class="tile" style="background-image: url('{{userpost.image}}');" >
                        <div class="circular" style="background: url(' {{post.user.profileimage}} ') no-repeat; background-size: 50px 50px; border:5px; border-color:#fff;"></div>
                        <div class="weather-text">
                          <span class="location">{{userpost.title}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tile" style="background-image: url('{{userpost.image}}');" >
                       <div class="circular" style="background: url(' {{post.user.profileimage}} ') no-repeat;  background-size: 50px 50px; border:5px; border-color:#fff;"></div>
                        <div class="weather-text">
                          <span class="temperature">{{userpost.message}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: creating a http://jsfiddle.net/ will be useful.

Comment: You are running your script before there even _is_ a `.tile-container` element. Thus, no click event gets bound to anything, and the change in formatting you see is due to the `:active` state only – and as we know, that only applies as long as the mouse button is pressed. Either make your script code run after the elements exist, or use event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop using the "active" pseudo class similar to what @AmuletxHeart is saying.  Remove the .tile-container:active selector from your CSS and change the classname that you're adding on click to something other than "active" to remove confusion.  I've created a jsfiddle that shows what you want: 
http://jsfiddle.net/inpursuit/g6pf2ye1/3/

```
$('.tile-container').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('beenclicked');
});

.tile-container.beenclicked {
   -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   -moz-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   -o-transform: translate(0px,-100%);
   transform: translate(0px,-100%);

   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
   -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transform: scale(1.0);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   transform: scale(1.0);
   width:450px;
   height:350px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem. Use Google Chrome, inspect element to debug your website. Press F12, click on the magnifying glass icon, then select the element you want to debug.

Basics of jQuery, check if DOM is fully loaded before running any scripts.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".tile").click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

The "active" css state is triggered when your mouse is held down. Depressing the button removes the "active" state from an element.

What you want to do is use the ".active" class instead:

Original

> .tile-container :active {...}

Corrected

> .tile-container .active {...}

When clicking on the square tiles, you are actually click the element with class "tile". I found that out by using the magnifying glass thing.

Also, I think you are confused between "tile-container" and "title-container". Notice the additional "t".

You need to change the jQuery to add the active class to the element with class "tile"

Original

```
$(".title-container").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Corrected

```
$(".tile").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean isn't that what im doing? @AmuletxHeart

Comment: I tried that as well, as well as the one below just changing it to this doens't work it doesnt expand at all..

Comment: What you are doing is add the class ".active" to the element with class ".title-container". When you do ".tile-container :active", you are checking if the element ".tile-container" has the state ":active". Notice, the difference. ":active" is like a temporary state that describes whether the element is being held down by a mouse click. ".active" is a more permanent class that is added to your element unless another script removes it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59389/discussion-between-amuletxheart-and-grant).

Answer (score 0):

Almost there.

In your css, you are only defining the `:active` pseudo-class.

Try out:

```
.tile-container:active, 
.tile-container.active {}
.tile-container:active > .tile, 
.tile-container.active > .tile {}
```

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes for more info on pseudo-classes.

Comment: my live example now reflects this but its still is only on hold down of the button.

Comment: Try $(".title-container").click(function(){
$(this).addClass("active"); });  -- Remove the "." before "active".

Comment: See CBroe's comment. Didn't even catch that the javascript was above the HTML body. Try moving the javascript to the end of the document, or use jQuery's .ready() method.